# How to reuse function in protocol with `associatedtype`?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, code-reuse, swift-extensions, associated-types

Consider the following situation:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T = String
    func f()
}

extension P {
    func f() {print("I want to reuse this function")}
}

class A: P {
    func f() {
        (self as P).f() // can't compile
        print("do more things.")
    }
}
```

If there is no `associatedtype`, the expression `(self as P).f()` is OK.
Is there a method to reuse `P.f()` when `P` has `associtedtype`?

Comment: Even if no `associatedtype`, calling of `(self as P).f()` will cause infinite loop error at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. But there's a simple workaround:

```
protocol P {
    associatedtype T = String
    func f()
}

extension P {
    func f() {g()}
    func g() {print("I want to reuse this function")}
}

class A: P {
    func f() {
        self.g() // no problem with compilation, calls protocol's implementation
        print("do more things.")
    }
}
```

Comment: That works only if we can modify the code of `f()` in `extension P`.

Comment: @蘇哲聖 No, it's sufficient to modify the code of class A. The problem here is that you're trying to get protocol-and-adopter to behave like superclass-and-subclass, which is silly. If you want to be able to call the extension's `f` just don't "override" it with another `f`.